# lean&fast way to make an addon work for all major browsers? firefox,chrome,[opera,internet explorer,safari]

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, greasemonkey, firefox-addon-sdk, crossrider

Yet there are tools to make one addon for all major browsers at once, 
see: crossrider, kangoextensions and http://besttoolbars.net/products/addon_framework

With greasemonkey and a converter to a full firefox addon,
i already made an addon, that does the following three simple things:

- check http status of external links with wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest, 
  (which won't work out with javascript alone as of cross-site-scriting policy.)
- manipulate the current page/dom through some regex
- inject an additional hosted javascript for automatic updates

**but is there any "cross-browser addon maker" capable of the 3 things above?**
(especially http to external links like GM_xmlhttpRequest) 
and open source, free or **at least** free of their branding in  the addons made with it?

or else what is the easierst way from my greasemonkey script to full addons for also 
chrome,[opera,internet explorer,safari(or more)].
(i imagine this alone could be a few kb of code to match the requirnments above and doesnt need to be a complex service like crossrider?)

Thanks!=)

Comment: Are you going to open a new question everyday with almost the same thing? And you want something to work in all browsers, but simpler than crossrider? That might be hard to find.

Comment: ola, thanks for your answer! (i deleted the previous question) i dont know yet if crossrider is overkill/allows to disable all branding/monetisation? Maybe someone knows more about besttoolbars.net/products/addon_framework and KangoExtensions or there is something simple, open source, that is not capable of all the browsers APIs but only fits my limited requirements for 1 or more of the major browsers?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve your goals using the [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com) platform, writing code once in JavaScript that works on all supported platforms. For your specific goals, you can use the [appAPI.request](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.request) API for your HTTP requests and jQuery/JS DOM to manipulate the page content.

Regarding branding, the Crossrider platform enables you to customize the extension using your own image, specify your own post-installation landing page (Thank You page), and either host a seamless installer widget on your site OR host a Windows installer file, and hence an end user does not see any Crossrider branding at all.

Finally, regarding monetization, we have a strict policy of only monetizing extensions with the mutual consent of the extension developer.

I hope this clarifies your concerns, but please feel free to ask any further questions either on this thread or by contacting our support (support@crossrider.com).

Disclaimer: I am a Crossrider employee

Comment: thanks! yay, so in short crossrider is tolerant but not exclusive to some developers who may decide for some addons to use crossrider once only and make their addon stay completely independent and maybe not to use the continuous services? (next to no branding, no or own monetizing only this may includes to disable reporting/the addon not to include any user tracking - or more (excuse i didn’t study the terms yet)) –

Comment: Apologies ... only just saw your comment. Correct, an extension built using the framework can never be completely independent, and hence if this is an issue for you then perhaps another platform may meet your needs. As with any platform/service/... it's a mater of finding which is the best match for your requirements ;-)